# Use string resources with testFixtures in Android Studio

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle, junit, android-gradle-plugin

[testFixtures](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.1/com/android/build/api/dsl/TestFixtures) have been introduced since AGP 7.0.

I have enabled the following in my `build.gradle`:

```
    testFixtures  {
        enable = true
        androidResources = true
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests.includeAndroidResources = true
    }
```

In my local unit tests I can reference strings resources (strings in `strings.xml`) placed in the main source set, but I can't access those placed  my testFixtures source set.

Placing string resources under the `src/testFixtures/res` folder, shows them on Android Studio just fine. But I can't reference them via `R.string.string_name` either on code found in the `testFixture` source path or the `test` source path.

I think that the appt is not picking them up.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

The strings can be accessed using the "test" or "testFixtures" package. Both of these can work:

- `com.your.module.namespace.testFixtures.R.string.string_name`
- `com.your.module.namespace.test.R.string.string_name`

Instead of specifying the whole path towards "R", you can use an import statement:

```java
import com.your.module.namespace.test.R;

private Context mockContext;

@Before
public void setUp() {
   // inject context provided by Robolectric
   mockContext = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext();
}

@Test
public void test() {
   mockContext.getString(R.string_name);
}
```

I am using `RobolectricTestRunner` to get a mockContext in my unit tests and access the string resources.

Note that Android Studio will not help with auto-complete and mark the string path with red color, but the unit tests will work just fine.

Also, note that this works when the unit tests and the string are in a library module. If they are in an app module, test fails with `package does not exist` error. This is an ongoing issue with Gradle and AGP.